# jquery: sort answers after cloning TR

Tags: jquery

i have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pihrig/je7p5e1f/
`enter code here`

add a couple Q&Q
then add a couple questions to a section.

I would like the questions ordered:

```
question2a1,
question2a2,
question2a3
```

right now it is:

```
question2a1,
question2a3,
question2a2
```

i have tried to do an after `( '.section' + secNum ':last')`
but i cant seem to be able to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here?

Comment: think i got it with help from co-worker! $('.section' + secNum + ':last').after(clonedRow);

Comment: this also did what i needed. $('tr.' + clonedRow.attr('class') + ':last').after(clonedRow); Thank you Mr. Ashworth!

Answer (score 0):

think i got it with help from co-worker! 
$('.section' + secNum + ':last').after(clonedRow);

this also did what i needed. 
$('tr.' + clonedRow.attr('class') + ':last').after(clonedRow);

Thank you Mr. Ashworth! –